# Send mail to remote server in PHP

Tags: php, html, email, smtp

As title mentions, I'm able to telnet to my web server with port 25.

But the problem is, this simple code here does not send email out. The output stated that it got sent out but there is no indication of email received.

```
$to = "mycompanyemail@company.com";
$subject = "test";
$msg = "Ite!";
$headers = "From: mycompanyemail@company.com\r\nReply-To: mycompanyemail@company.com";
mail("$to", "$subject", "$msg", "$headers");
echo "finished!";
echo "Your mail was sent.";
```

As following shows my php.ini file configuration

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = smtp.realtest.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = mycompanyemail@company.com
```

I've been stucked in this dire situation for two weeks and as per previous topic, there has been no help and offer, I really need this to be up and going. Thank you guys. Sorry for my inexperience effort.

On another side note, I realized how is it possible to send email from an email address if there is no authentication needed? Please answer my clarifications, thanks alot.

Comment: You *are* running Win32, right?

Comment: hosted server? shared host? vps?

Comment: how do you know it is sent? does `mail` return true?

Comment: Do you even have a mail server set up?

Comment: @Ignacio Yes i am running Win32.
-Dagon It is a hosted server running in the company.
-Alex Mail returned true as per if else statement.
-Jack Mail server? I thought all you need to do is just to set the SMTP server and send the email to the SMTP server? What sort of mail server do you need to set up?

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

You might try these links 
http://roshanbh.com.np/2007/12/sending-e-mail-from-localhost-in-php-in-windows-environment.html and http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mail.php (you'll find can also use sendmail on windows ;) )

Also the e-mail address specified for `sendmail_from` must exist on the SMTP server, and make sure the IP of the computer you are running the script on is trusted by the SMTP server, so it does not ask for authentication or encryption.

And don't forget the security, if you are planning to use it in production.